# ClipToBounds with no border colour issue - Xamarin.iOS, C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, uiimageview

**Program:**

- I have a UIImageView. The image view has an image, a border and a
  corner radius (rounded).
- The image view property "ClipsToBounds" is set to true so the image
  matches the rounded corners.

**Code:**

```
UIImageView imageView = new UIImageView(); 
imageView.Layer.BorderWidth = 5f; //set border thickness
imageView.Layer.CornerRadius = 25; //make corner's rounded
imageView.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Red.CGColor; //set border color red
imageView.Image = new UIImage(imgPath); //set img
imageView.ClipsToBounds = true; //required - so image is rounded
```

**Problem:**

If I change the border colour to white (transparent) you can see small black lines at every corner. **How can I get rid of these?**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it maybe have a shadow? Set the shadow color to transparent as well to be sure.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Just tried it, it's not the shadow but thanks.

Comment: @SushiHangover I am testing it on an actual device, iPad Air 2

Comment: @t3ch3 As a test, try setting the border to transparent (`UIColor.Clear`) to see if those artifacts disappear.

Comment: @SushiHangover Yes they did disappear! Unfortunately I don't think setting the border colour to Clear is an option for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the core animation layers that being rendered via Revel on the border radius and those are rendering artifacts on the composite (I *assume* those are rounding errors in the mini-map/anti-aliasing in the radius calculations of the original image color, but that is just a wild guess...)

[image]

So if you create a `CAShapeLayer` with the same radius you are using and apply it as the layer's mask, the artifact becomes smaller. (The Core Animation bezier path is more accurate but not perfect?)

[image]

If you create a CAShapeLayer that is one pixel larger on the corner's radius as a "hack", the artifacts are totally masked:

[image]

#### CAShapeLayer/Mask Fix-up Example:

```
UIImageView imageView = new UIImageView
{
    Image = UIImage.FromBundle("foo.jpg"),
    ClipsToBounds = true,
    Bounds = View.Bounds
};
imageView.Layer.BorderWidth = 5f; //set border thickness
imageView.Layer.CornerRadius = 25; //make corner's rounded
imageView.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.White.CGColor; //set border color red
var maskingShapeLayer = new CAShapeLayer()
{
    Path = UIBezierPath.FromRoundedRect(imageView.Bounds, UIRectCorner.AllCorners, new CGSize(26, 26)).CGPath
};
imageView.Layer.Mask = maskingShapeLayer;
```

**Note:** Maybe someone that is a "hard-core" Core Animation expert can explain way the rendering artifacts exist on these border curves in the first place as I still use CAShapeLayers to do my corner masking which do not have the rendering artifacts even though in iOS 11+ you can just set your UIView's Layer.CornerRadius like the question does.

Comment: @t3ch3 No problem, Still want to know why iOS does that on `CornerRadius` and not on a `CAShapeLayer`.... ;-) 